# Customize swagger in ASP.net Core to pull routes from .json file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I am developing a simple API gateway (or a pass-through API) to forward request to third party end points, getting response and send it back to user. I added my routes and destination end points in a .json file. it looks like somewhat like this

```
{
"routes": [
{
  "endpoint": "/api1",
  "destination": {
    "path": "https://api.example.com/v1/"       
  }
},
{
  "endpoint": "/api2",
  "destination": {
    "path": "https://api.example1.com/v3/"       
  }
}
  ]
}
```

If user types in 'api1', the program send request to 'https://api.example.com/v1/' url using HttpClient. There are no controllers or action methods involved.
I have followed the tutorial to do the basic implementation 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Is there any way I can use swagger to pull routes from preceding json snippet? or somehow override /swagger/v1/swagger.json file to manually add all paths.
I have Implemented this API as mentioned in following link
https://medium.com/streamwriter/api-gateway-aspnet-core-a46ef259dc54